# knitr::opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE) does not work

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I tried to suppress R message in R markdown file with `knitr::opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE)` 
but it didn't work.

I have updated RStudio, R and knitr, with no difference. I ran the code on both Mac and Window with the same results.

The below code will show the message "message is set to FALSE"

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE)
strMessage <- if_else(knitr::opts_chunk$get("message"),"TRUE","FALSE")
message(c("message is set to ",strMessage))
```

If I use `{r message=FALSE}` the message would not show up.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes made with `knitr::opts_chunk$set` will be activated starting th next chunk. See my example above. So it is recommended to setup your setting in the first chunk of your RMD file and then calculate/manipulate ... your data. See the official documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/knitr/versions/1.22/topics/opts_chunk) under `Details`.

````
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE)
strMessage <- if_else(knitr::opts_chunk$get("message"),"TRUE","FALSE")
message(c("message is set to ",strMessage))
```

```{r}
strMessage <- if_else(knitr::opts_chunk$get("message"),"TRUE","FALSE")
message(c("message is set to ",strMessage))
```
````

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I copied and pasted your example. It didn't seem to work at first, but then I found it depends on the output file type. It works when I change the output to html_document, but not when it's html_notebook. Is it a known bug for R notebook or I did wrong on something?